# Ob_start filtering closes <script> tag wrong

Tags: php

I am using ob_start to filter a WordPress backend page.
My script looks like this:

```php
function remove_extra_field_profile()

{

    $current_file_url =  preg_replace( "#\?.*#" , "" , basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );

    if( $current_file_url == "profile.php" )
    {
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', function(){ ob_start("profile_callback"); } );
        add_action( 'shutdown', function(){ ob_end_flush(); } );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_extra_field_profile' );


function profile_callback( $html )
{
    $profile_dom = new DOMDocument;
    $profile_dom->loadHTML( $html );

    $all_lines = $profile_dom->getElementsByTagname( 'tr' );

    $excludes = array(
        'user-syntax-highlighting-wrap',
        'user-rich-editing-wrap'
        );

    $deletes = array();

    foreach ( $all_lines as $line ) 
    {
        $tr_calss = $line->getAttribute("class");

        if( in_array( $tr_calss, $excludes ) )
        {
            $deletes[] = $line;
        }
    }

    $deletes[] = $profile_dom->getElementsByTagname( 'h2' )->item(0);

    foreach ($deletes as $delete) 
    {
        $delete->parentNode->removeChild( $delete );
    }

    return $profile_dom->saveHTML();
}
```

this works fine.

But once I add a plugin which adds a select field to profile.php (wordpress adds somethings automatically), things get strange:

With the "filtering-script" from above in place, the closing `</script>` tag (which is supposed to be at the end) will be moved forward:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-media-frame">
        <div class="media-frame-menu"></script></div>
        <div class="media-frame-title"></div>
        <div class="media-frame-router"></div>
        <div class="media-frame-content"></div>
        <div class="media-frame-toolbar"></div>
        <div class="media-frame-uploader"></div>
```

Once I remove the PHP script, everything is fine.

Why is the script affecting this `<script>` part? What can I do differently?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is there need for  `div` inside `<script>` tags?

Comment: I don't know, it comes from WordPress - no matter what plugin I use, once there is an upload field (created by WordPress) it shows up like that.

Comment: @Ingus See: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7a92316fd8c07493e7f49e494dc19e18773bb5fa/wp-includes/media-template.php#L179